# how to perform redirection in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is my first webpage in php.I have created a log in page.I have successfully logged in.I need to redirect  the webpage to the  user's profile with a message of welcome user.
how to do it?
This is my code where should i add the redirect code?
thank you in advance

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="userdetails";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if(!$conn){
die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$qry = "select * from userdetails where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$LoginName="";
$result=$conn->query($qry);
if($result->num_rows>0){
while($loginuser=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $LoginName=$loginuser['username'];
}

}


?>
```

Comment: Follow the link `This question already has an answer here:` and you will see e very good answer. In future start by searching for an answer to your question that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but you have to make sure this is the **first** code to output on the page.

```
header('Location: page.php');
```

Comment: @ Thaillie where should i place it